# All Appointment view Grid become inline editable in Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there any way to change the All Appointment View grid become inline editable grid? [This is the All Appointment page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gPBW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Not from the out-of-the-box CRM. However, there are addons for that. Like from PowerObjects or Sonoma partners, to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-the-box does not provide this feature! Find some of the possible options here:
https://salimadamoncrm.com/2015/09/01/dynamics-crm-what-options-for-editable-grids/

You can create your won:
 - Find free js+html grid
 - Use Xrm object and odata API to build your desired functionality.